# extrema of volume of solid of revolutions

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, solid-of-revolution

Based on the definition of the volume of a solid of revolution, i wanted to apply Euler equation and find the extrema as follows:
$$
v = \pi\int^{a}_{b}{y^2dx}
$$
using euler equation:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})=0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2ydx, \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})=0
$$
so it yields:
$$
2y\cdot dx = 0
$$
so i dont get it, what i am supposed to do afterwards? how do  i integrate $2ydx$ ? does it even mean anything?

Comment: yes i noticed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now i see that i made a mistake puting the dx in the equation which is something that cant be solved and is meaningless, on the other hand the euler lagrange equations yields the solution y = 0, which is a minima. that is, because the euler lagranage equation only yields extrema.

Comment: Correct; you won't get any “interesting” results without further constraints on $y$.